# Python - Convert pyodbc code to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have pyodbc code that I use to connect to a DSN, however for some reason it is no longer working and I cannot figure out why (the drivers are empty even though they are there).

So I want to try and convert everything to use SQLAlchemy instead.

My current code for connecting to the database is:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=QueryBuilder')
cursor = conn.cursor()
stringA = "SELECT GrantInformation.Call FROM GrantInformation"
cursor.execute(stringA)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

How would I get this to do the same in SQLAlchemy, I have checked the documentation and I am still confused.

Many thanks

---

I used:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("""{}://{}:{}@{}/{}"""
                           .format(SQL Server,nick,mypassword,myservername,querybuilder))

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT GrantInformation.Call FROM GrantInformation")
```

and I got:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-f7837462519f>", line 4
    .format(SQL Server,nick,mypassword,myservername,querybuilder))
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

Also declared the variables before, and I now get:

```
ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'SQL Server://nick:mypassword@myhost/querybuilder'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("""{}://{}:{}@{}/{}"""
                           .format(driver,user,password,host,database))

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT GrantInformation.Call FROM GrantInformation", engine)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the quick reply. I tried using your answer and I got invalid syntax. I tried using quote marks for all the entries and still getting syntax errors. I added what I did to my question. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: yes use quotes for all the entries. If you are using SQL Server then try `driver='mssql'`.

Comment: Hmmm. maybe something wrong with my install... getting: C:\Users\nick\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.py:92: SAWarning: No driver name specified; this is expected by PyODBC when using DSN-less connections
  "No driver name specified; "

Comment: And then: TypeError: read_sql_query() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'

Comment: sorry forgot to add `engine` to the `read_sql_query`, edited now. Regarding the error on the driver, try `mssql+pyodbc`

Comment: Hey, ye, sorry, I worked out the engine part... mssql+pyodbc isnt working either. I get a DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') error :/

Comment: try this: `engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://nick:mypassword@myhost/querybuilder?driver=Microsoft+ODBC+Driver+for+SQL+Server')` basically adding the driver part to your string.

Comment: Thank you. I got it working with: engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://nick:password@QueryBuilder")

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the below code format to create engine

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# default
engine = create_engine('mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')

# mysql-python
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')

# MySQL-connector-python
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')

# OurSQL
engine = create_engine('mysql+oursql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')

# query
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select username from users")
```

database name = foo, username = scott, password = tiger, host = localhost

Reference: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html

Comment: Hey, thank you. I am not using mysql unfortunately I am using SQL server so it isnt finding the database :/